# Erro variável dentro da função

Tags: php, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis

Estou tendo problemas e pelo que procurei nos fóruns da internet, outros tem a mesma dúvida que eu.

Não consigo usar variáveis PHP dentro da função de transação. Como faço para setar uma variável?

Por exemplo, isto não funciona:

```
$id = $_POST["id_saida"];
$nome = $_POST["nome_produto"];
$valor   = $_POST["valor_final"];


class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox
{
public static function main()
{
```

Original:

```
$paymentRequest->addItem('0001', 'Notebook prata', 1, 430.00); //original
```

Como gostaria que funcionasse:

```
$paymentRequest->addItem($id, $nome, $n, $valor); // como gostaria
```

Só que dá erro, vem vazia. O que fazer?

```
<?php

require_once "includes/ps/PagSeguroLibrary/PagSeguroLibrary.php";
$form = $_GET['form'];
if ($form == "pagseg"){
echo "ok";
$id_transfer = $_POST["id_transfer"];
$id = $_POST["id_saida"];
$nome = $_POST["nome_produto"];
$valor   = $_POST["valor_final"];

$v1 ="teste";

/**
* Class with a main method to illustrate the usage of the domain class     
PagSeguroPaymentRequest
*/
class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox
{
    public static function main()
    {
        // Instantiate a new payment request
        $paymentRequest = new PagSeguroPaymentRequest();

        // Set the currency
        $paymentRequest->setCurrency("BRL");

        // Add an item for this payment request
        $paymentRequest->addItem($v1, 'Notebook prata', 1, 430.00);

        // Set a reference code for this payment request, it is useful to identify this   
      payment
        // in future notifications.
        $paymentRequest->setReference("REF123");

        // Set shipping information for this payment request
        $sedexCode = PagSeguroShippingType::getCodeByType('SEDEX');
        $paymentRequest->setShippingType($sedexCode);
        $paymentRequest->setShippingAddress(
            '01452002',
            'Av. Brig. Faria Lima',
            '1384',
            'apto. 114',
            'Jardim Paulistano',
            'São Paulo',
            'SP',
            'BRA'
        );

        // Set your customer information.
        $paymentRequest->setSender(
            'João Comprador',
            'email@comprador.com.br',
            '11',
            '56273440',
            'CPF',
            '156.009.442-76'
        );

        // Set the url used by PagSeguro to redirect user after checkout process ends
        $paymentRequest->setRedirectUrl("http://www.lojamodelo.com.br");

        // Add checkout metadata information
        $paymentRequest->addMetadata('PASSENGER_CPF', '15600944276', 1);
        $paymentRequest->addMetadata('GAME_NAME', 'DOTA');
        $paymentRequest->addMetadata('PASSENGER_PASSPORT', '23456', 1);

        // Another way to set checkout parameters
        $paymentRequest->addParameter('notificationURL', 'http://www.lojamodelo.com.br/nas');
        $paymentRequest->addParameter('senderBornDate', '07/05/1981');
        $paymentRequest->addIndexedParameter('itemId', '0003', 3);
        $paymentRequest->addIndexedParameter('itemDescription', 'Notebook Preto', 3);
        $paymentRequest->addIndexedParameter('itemQuantity', '1', 3);
        $paymentRequest->addIndexedParameter('itemAmount', '200.00', 3);

        try {

            /*
             * #### Credentials #####
             * Replace the parameters below with your credentials
             * You can also get your credentials from a config file. See an example:
             * $credentials = PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials();
             */

            // seller authentication
            $credentials = new PagSeguroAccountCredentials("fabioh.rangel@gmail.com",
                "EDC2E4A8E6B246D29C713FB97C26808E");

            // application authentication
            //$credentials = PagSeguroConfig::getApplicationCredentials();

            //$credentials->setAuthorizationCode("E231B2C9BCC8474DA2E260B6C8CF60D3");

            // Register this payment request in PagSeguro to obtain the checkout code
            $onlyCheckoutCode = true;
            $code = $paymentRequest->register($credentials, $onlyCheckoutCode);

            self::printPaymentUrl($code);
        } catch (PagSeguroServiceException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
      }

      public static function printPaymentUrl($code)
      {
        if ($code) {
            echo "<h2>Criando requisi&ccedil;&atilde;o de pagamento</h2>";
            echo "<p>Code: <strong>$code</strong></p>";
            echo "<script>
            PagSeguroLightbox('".$code."');
                  </script>";

        }
      }
     }
}
CreatePaymentRequestLightbox::main();
```

Comment: Qual o erro que está sendo retornado?

Comment: Você passou essas variáveis como parâmetro na função?

Comment: Erro [HTTP 400] - BAD_REQUEST 0 [11025] - Item Id is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se você colocou código e informação suficiente para indicar com clareza onde está o problema mas certamente tem uma coisa que vai ajudar ou resolver o problema. Provavelmente basta transferir a declaração das variáveis que estão "soltas" na página e colocar dentro do método onde você precisa delas, no caso o `main` da classe `CreatePaymentRequestLightbox`. Eu tenho minhas dúvidas se você precisa desta classe. Provavelmente você está copiando um código que você não entende o que faz.

```
<?php
require_once "includes/ps/PagSeguroLibrary/PagSeguroLibrary.php";
class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox {

public static function main() {
    $form = $_GET['form'];
    $id_transfer = $_POST["id_transfer"];
    $id = $_POST["id_saida"];
    $nome = $_POST["nome_produto"];
    $valor   = $_POST["valor_final"];
    $v1 ="teste";

    $paymentRequest = new PagSeguroPaymentRequest();
    $paymentRequest->setCurrency("BRL");
    $paymentRequest->addItem($v1, 'Notebook prata', 1, 430.00);
    $paymentRequest->setReference("REF123");
    $sedexCode = PagSeguroShippingType::getCodeByType('SEDEX');
    $paymentRequest->setShippingType($sedexCode);
    $paymentRequest->setShippingAddress(
        '01452002',
        'Av. Brig. Faria Lima',
        '1384',
        'apto. 114',
        'Jardim Paulistano',
        'São Paulo',
        'SP',
        'BRA'
    );
    $paymentRequest->setSender(
        'João Comprador',
        'email@comprador.com.br',
        '11',
        '56273440',
        'CPF',
        '156.009.442-76'
    );
    $paymentRequest->setRedirectUrl("http://www.lojamodelo.com.br");
    $paymentRequest->addMetadata('PASSENGER_CPF', '15600944276', 1);
    $paymentRequest->addMetadata('GAME_NAME', 'DOTA');
    $paymentRequest->addMetadata('PASSENGER_PASSPORT', '23456', 1);
    $paymentRequest->addParameter('notificationURL', 'http://www.lojamodelo.com.br/nas');
    $paymentRequest->addParameter('senderBornDate', '07/05/1981');
    $paymentRequest->addIndexedParameter('itemId', '0003', 3);
    $paymentRequest->addIndexedParameter('itemDescription', 'Notebook Preto', 3);
    $paymentRequest->addIndexedParameter('itemQuantity', '1', 3);
    $paymentRequest->addIndexedParameter('itemAmount', '200.00', 3);
    try {
        $credentials = new PagSeguroAccountCredentials("fabioh.rangel@gmail.com",
            "EDC2E4A8E6B246D29C713FB97C26808E");
        $onlyCheckoutCode = true;
        $code = $paymentRequest->register($credentials, $onlyCheckoutCode);
        self::printPaymentUrl($code);
    } catch (PagSeguroServiceException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
  }

  public static function printPaymentUrl($code) {
    if ($code) {
        echo "<h2>Criando requisi&ccedil;&atilde;o de pagamento</h2>";
        echo "<p>Code: <strong>$code</strong></p>";
        echo "<script>
        PagSeguroLightbox('".$code."');
              </script>";
    }
  }
 }
}
CreatePaymentRequestLightbox::main();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Variable.php).

Answer (score 1):

As varíaveis que você está tentando utilizar no método do objeto `$paymentRequest` devem ser inicializadas dentro do método principal (`main`), assim elas serão reconhecidas no escopo.

Answer (score 0):

Pra você usar esses parâmetros em toda a aplicação (ou em mais de uma classe), o melhor, na minha opnião, é criar uma constante. Exemplo:

```
define("ID", $_POST["id_saida"]);
define("NOME", $_POST["nome_produto"]);
define("VALOR", $_POST["valor_final"])  ;

class CreatePaymentRequestLightbox
{
    public static function main()
    {
        $id = ID;
        $nome = NOME;
        $valor   = VALOR;
    }
}
```